# Matlab multiply logical matrix and numeric matrix on GPU

Tags: matlab, matrix, gpu

When I do sample on GPU, for example

```
>> a = rand(3,5, 'gpuArray');
>> a = a > rand(size(a), 'gpuArray');
>> b = rand(5,3, 'gpuArray');
>> c = b * a; %where mistake happens,just said misuse *,  
MTIMES do not fully support integer class,at least one input is scalar.
```

So how can I solve this question?
Just use

```
>> a = double(a);
>> b = rand(5,3, 'gpuArray');
>> c = b * a;
```

I know I can do this, but is there any nicer solutions, such as I can multiply it directly?

Answer (score 1):

There are no other solutions that are "nice".  As you have already discovered, MATLAB only supports matrix multiplication using floating-point types (`double`, `single`, etc.).  This is well-understood behaviour in MATLAB.  You **must** ensure both types are of a supported type.